# Can digital printers do print Pantone colours?

Tags: pantone

there is this company they do digital printing with HP indigo digital technology that they claims is like offset quality...anyway I was wondering if they can print PMS colors as well? thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with "didgital printing"? Your question is not clear for me, explain it better, please.

Comment: @kurt: Digital printing means it is not an offset press. It usually means very high end laser printer meant for small-to-medium quantity print runs.

Answer (score 2):

No... but....

HP has taken specific steps to allow the Indigo system to *match* Pantone colors.

http://www8.hp.com/us/en/commercial-printers/indigo-presses/ink-media.html

And you can check out page 4 of this PDF: http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetPDF.aspx%2F4AA3-9325EEW.pdf

---

This was all discovered by simply typing "Does the HP indigo digital technology support spot color" into a Google search.